# Is there a way to demonstrate that the time within Azure is synced with NIST time?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way in Azure App Services to demonstrate that the time within Azure is synced with NIST time http://www.time.gov/?  In other server environments, I believe this was done with a command line that shows the server address is set to sync with time servers listed at http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Windows Servers use the time service at `time.windows.com` which is based on [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) by default to provide the computer with the correct time. And you could choose your preferred time source within the Date and Time Control Panel applet as follows:

[image]

For apps host on the Azure Web App, you could retrieve the current time service via KUDU. Here is a sample, you could refer to it.

1. Log in to KUDU by visiting `https://<your-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net`, click Debug console > CMD, change the dir to system32 by inputting `cd..\windows\system32`
2. Retrieve the current time server by inputting the following command:

   `reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters /v NtpServer`

Then, you could get the following result:

[image]

Additionally, you could refer to [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263(WS.10).aspx?tduid=(bce0efeef7c848fa0b082ec5c0b35521)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-8oaAltq88.ALiU9CQiCwgg)()#w2k3tr_times_tools_dyax) for a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webapp that displays the result of `DateTime.UtcNow`